# Find and highlight selected consecutive cells from one column in other columns

Tags: excel

I would like to know if there is any formula/conditional formating I can use, where I can select some consecutive cells in one column and this formula will find and highlight the same cells in other columns. For example, as you can see in the image below
[image]

I have selected the cells

```
2-0
1-0
n12
x22
```

from column A, and there are the same entries with the same order in other columns as well ( E, H, and K).
The data cannot be sorted.
Is there any formula I can use for this job?

Answer (score 0):

While not the most straightforward solution, you can indeed use Conditional Formatting function for that purpose.

Mark the cells from Columns B - K of your sheet, then click on `Home` -> `Conditional Formatting` and select `Classic` as style.

In the next window, select `Only format cells that contain` and underneath select `Specific text`. In the field on the right hand side, you can then add e.g. `2-0` as the trigger text and chose a formatting rule in the field at the bottom of the window. That should solve your problem.

Comment: But this will find and highlight a single cell and not multiple selected.